# Populating a program with data.. Visual Studio 2012 & SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to populate a database I creaed for a project and got this error...

> 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' does not contain a definition
>   for 'ItemsSource' and no extension method 'ItemsSource' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Code:

```
namespace WalkthroughV2 { 
        ///<summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        { 
           private List<Student> studentList;


            }

            private void Refresh()
            {
                StudentService studentService = new StudentService();

                studentList = studentService.GetAll();
                grdData.ItemsSource = studentList;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please provide proper formatting and a real question. If you're new to this site and its concept you might consult the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: You have a compile error?  Go to the offending line of code and correct the syntax.

Comment: Do you mean `grdData.DataSource` instead of `ItemsSource`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add rows and columns programmatically, as shown in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752271%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A small example:

```
Grid myGrid = new Grid();
ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition();
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);

// Add the first text cell to the Grid
TextBlock txt1 = new TextBlock();
txt1.Text = "2005 Products Shipped";
txt1.FontSize = 20; 
txt1.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
Grid.SetColumnSpan(txt1, 3);
Grid.SetRow(txt1, 0);
```

A full tutorial can be found in the [same document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752271%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

To solve your problem of why `ItemsSource` is not available; you are using a Grid. In your WPF-Project, there is also a `DataGrid` available.

A tutorial shown in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340709%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains how to display data in a `DataGrid`.

```
ObjectQuery<Product> products = dataEntities.Products;

var query =
    from product in products
    where product.Color == "Red" 
    orderby product.ListPrice
    select new { product.Name, product.Color, CategoryName = product.ProductCategory.Name, product.ListPrice };

 dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

And the DataGrid has to be placed **inside** a Grid:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridSQLExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="450" 
    Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
          <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```